# own command within external command line application

Tags: bash

I built a small bash menu like this:

```
read choice_nr

case $choice_nr in
        1 ) newsbeuter ;;
        2 ) echo "some other option"
esac
```

I'd like to make a shortcut within external applications (like newsbeuter) so it restarts the menu. So imagine I open this menu, type 1 to select newsbeuter and then the main menu of newsbeuter is displayed. At that moment I'd like to be able to press some button on my keyboard to open my own menu again.

I'm sorry for the vagueness of this question, I found it difficult to look for help myself since I don't know what exactly I have to search for.

Comment: You want to add an option to a menu in some other app you didn't write? Basically impossible.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
while true; do
  read choice_nr
  case $choice_nr in
        1 ) newsbeuter 
            ;;
        2 ) echo "some other option"
  esac
done
```